EF core code first haskey option creating both clustered index as well as unique constraint
I have a .Net Core Entity Framework code first web API solution. I am trying to create new model using code first approach. I have used "HasKey" option but it is a creating clustered index and a unique constraint as well. Clustered index can be understandable however, it is not clear why it is creating a unique constraint. I do not want to create additional unique constraint on it.
I have tried below code but it is creating a unique constraint
[Table("VendorBrandsPromotion")]
public class VendorBrandPromoTable
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid VendorId { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string CustomerGroup { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnableDateValidation { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public string HeaderText { get; set; }
    public string BodyText { get; set; }
    public string PromotionText { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BrandsPromotionProductsTable> BrandsPromotionProducts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BrandsPromotionImagesTable> BrandsPromotionImages { get; set; }


    //Config
    public class DbConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<VendorBrandPromoTable>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<VendorBrandPromoTable> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(v => new { v.Id, v.VendorId });
            builder.Property(v => v.Brand).HasMaxLength(500).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(v => v.Location).HasMaxLength(500);
            builder.Property(v => v.CustomerGroup).HasMaxLength(500);
            builder.Property(v => v.HeaderText).HasMaxLength(500);
            builder.Property(v => v.BodyText).HasMaxLength(1000);
            builder.Property(v => v.PromotionText).HasMaxLength(80);
            builder.HasMany(v => v.BrandsPromotionProducts).WithOne(v => v.VendorBrandPromo).HasForeignKey(v => new { v.VendorPromotionId }).HasPrincipalKey(v => new { v.Id });
            builder.HasMany(v => v.BrandsPromotionImages).WithOne(v => v.VendorBrandPromo).HasForeignKey(v => new { v.VendorPromotionId }).HasPrincipalKey(v => new { v.Id });
        }
    }
}

what and where I am doing wrong here?

Please indicate both the EF Core and ASP.NET Core versions.

Could you please share the BrandsPromotionProductsTable and BrandsPromotionImagesTable class, besides, what's the relationship for the Id and VendorId? You set two key for one table which make the error.
